# How to specify 'Not found' error pages in web.xml such that the url is also changed?

Tags: java, html, servlets, server

If I specify an error page like this :

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pages/not-found.html</location>
</error-page>
```

and hit a url `localhost:8080/app/something/else` (which returns 404 error), then the URL on the browser remains `localhost:8080/app/something/else` while the error page's content is dumped on the browser. The problem here is that if I specify any css resource like this :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

then, the browser tries to load `localhost:8080/app/something/else/resources/css/bootstrap.css` instead of `localhost:8080/app/resources/css/bootstrap.css`, which obviously fails. We also can't use

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />`

as the browser will then load `localhost:8080/resources/css/bootstrap.css`

The basic problem is that the relative path is dependent on the number of slashes there are in the URL.

In my opinion, if I can ***redirect*** the page to /pages/not-found.html, then I can be specify a consistent path of the css files (without worrying about the number of slashes in the URL)

Answer (score 0):

If You are talking about a **JSF-Application** maybe You can use a phaselistener:

In the phaselistener you can let JSF do its work and catch the java.io.FileNotFoundException. In case the exception occurs You can forward the user to a special site:

```
 FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();
 context.getExternalContext().redirect("/pages/not-found.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this like
for CSS file

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css"/>
```

and for javascript file

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js"/>
```

or if you want to do as you use

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

but it is better to use it in the first place